# Прерывистая анимации до конца желаемого результата

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

CodePen: https://codepen.io/jkmg/pen/zYKqvLq

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background-color: purple;
        }
        svg {
            height: 50px;
        }
        .playButton {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            display: inline-flex;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -50px;
            margin-top: -50px;
            border-radius: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .playButton .poscont {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .playButton .playGlyph {
            opacity: 1;
            margin-right: -5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <span></span>
        <div class="playButton currentlyPaused">
          <div class="playGlyphPosition poscont">
          <svg class="playGlyph One" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70.83 122.58">
            
            <path id="playPath" d="M20.55,119.08a11.89,11.89,0,0,1-20.3-8.35L0,61.29.25,11.85a11.89,11.89,0,0,1,20.3-8.34l45,45a18.11,18.11,0,0,1,0,25.62Z"> 
            <animate xlink:href="#playPath"
                     begin="indefinite"
                     id="pauseAni"
                     attributeName="d"
                     dur="1s"
                     fill="freeze"
                     attributeType="XML"
                     from="M20.55,119.08a11.89,11.89,0,0,1-20.3-8.35L0,61.29.25,11.85a11.89,11.89,0,0,1,20.3-8.34l45,45a18.11,18.11,0,0,1,0,25.62Z"
                     to="M20.55,109.49c0,15-20.3,15-20.3-.06L0,60,.25,10.55c0-14.06,20.3-14.06,20.3-.06l0,36.69c.31,7.31.31,16.31,0,25.62Z"
                     />
            </path>
          </svg>
            </div>
          
        </div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.querySelector(".playButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
              if (this.classList.contains("currentlyPaused")) {
                this.classList.remove("currentlyPaused"); 
                this.classList.add("currentlyPlaying");
                document.querySelector("#pauseAni").beginElement();
                document.querySelector("span").innerText += "\nAttempted to play, ani to pause.";
              }
              else { 
                this.classList.remove("currentlyPlaying");
                this.classList.add("currentlyPaused");
                // document.querySelector("#playAni").beginElement();
                // this.querySelector(".playGlyph").classList.add("playing");
                document.querySelector("span").innerText += "\nAttempted to pause, ani to play.";
              }
            
            });
                </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь анимировать кнопку воспроизведения в кнопку паузы и преобразовать обратно после повторного клика, кнопку паузы в кнопку воспроизведения.

Я понятия не имею, почему анимация,  с помощью CSS, переходит к концу анимации, фактически не "анимируя".

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне разобраться в том, что происходит?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animation Skipping to End of Desired Result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65165967/7394871) от участника  [@jkmgme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11491069/jkmgme).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65165967/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Как прокомментировал @Robert Longson и как показано в ответе @Paul LeBeau , причина не плавной анимации связана с отсутствием требований:

1. Количество узловых точек в начальном `path` и в конечном `path` должна быть одинаковым. Это требование выполнено.
2. Тип Узловыx точек должен быть одинаковый на одинаковых позициях в обоих path

Чтобы выполнить эти требования к начальному и конечному пути можно воспользоваться техникой редактирования в векторном редакторе,

Начальный `path`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечный `path`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остается скопировать эти `path` и добавить в ваш код.
Я заменил код вашего скрипта. Наверное можно использовать любой скрипт, который выполняет  функции тригера.

```js
var svg_1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  pause = document.getElementById("pause"),
  play = document.getElementById("play");

let flag = true;

svg_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    pause.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    play.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: purple;
    }
    svg {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .playButton {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .playButton .poscont {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .playButton .playGlyph {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: -5px;
        pointer-events:all;
    }
</style>
<div class="playButton currentlyPaused">
      <div class="playGlyphPosition poscont">
      <svg id="svg1" class="playGlyph One" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70.83 122.58">
            
  <path d="m20.6 119.1c-5 5.3-20.3 2.2-20.3-8.3L0 61.3 0.3 11.9C0.3 1.3 15.4-1.2 20.6 3.5 26.3 8.8 29.4 12.3 35.8 18.9 43.7 26.9 50.8 35.1 58.7 42.7 73.9 57.3 74.6 64.7 59.1 80.7 52.6 87.5 46.5 92.5 36.1 103 29.2 110.1 27.5 111.8 20.6 119.1Z" style="fill:black;stroke:#000">
   
   <animate id="play" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeType="XML"
    to="m20.6 119.1c-5 5.3-20.3 2.2-20.3-8.3L0 61.3 0.3 11.9C0.3 1.3 15.4-1.2 20.6 3.5 26.3 8.8 29.4 12.3 35.8 18.9 43.7 26.9 50.8 35.1 58.7 42.7 73.9 57.3 74.6 64.7 59.1 80.7 52.6 87.5 46.5 92.5 36.1 103 29.2 110.1 27.5 111.8 20.6 119.1Z" />
 
 <animate id="pause" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeType="XML"
    to="M20.6 111C20.5 125.5 0.3 125.7 0.3 110.7L0 61.3 0.3 17c0-21.4 20.2-20.6 20.2-0.1 0 6.4 0 10 0 12.8 0 11.8 0.2 7.5 0.2 13-0.2 21.6-0.2 15.4 0 38.1 0.1 9.3 0.1 18.9 0 22.6-0.1 4.3-0.1 3.3-0.1 7.5z"/>
  </path>
</svg>
  </div>
      
    </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65170879/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>